# Highcharts gantt chart with multi-colored bars

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know if you can have multiple colors within a bar on a Highcharts gantt chart? I have the gantt chart working but would like to start with a color like green and fade to red towards the center of the bar and then back to green at the opposite end of the bar.

Comment: Have you tried to use linearGradient ? http://jsfiddle.net/PJPDz/1/

Comment: As per your suggestion I am trying linearGradient in this JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/psoderlund/M6jrX/2/) but its not using the gradient just solid colors. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you update your example, because doens't work, as I see.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to the point where it works. When I add the plotOption for color it stops showing the lines. This is the color code I removed from inside the plotOptions:,
             color: [{
                 linearGradient: perShapeGradient,
                    stops: [
                                [0, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'],
                                [1, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)']
                           ]
             }]